# Xamarin.Android invoking the editor of EditText manually

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I have an EditText (called Stock). I added a EditorAction to Stock. When I click on Stock the editor is opened and everything works as intended. Now I want the same behaviour but invoked from a different part in the code. I tried to call Stock.CallOnClick() but nothing happened. I was under the impression that the opening of the Editor was caused by the OnClick() event.

What would be the correct call to simulate the same behaviour of a tap of the EditText?

Thanks.

Comment: Any updates to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to call the InputMethodManager and call ShowSoftInput() where you want it and HideSoftInput() in your editoraction event.

```
        buttonStock.Click += delegate
        {
            stock.RequestFocus(); // this seems to be necessary
            stock.SelectAll(); // this is convenient
            var imm = ((InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService));
            imm.ShowSoftInput(stock, ShowFlags.Forced);
        };
```

stock is my EditText.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want the same behaviour but invoked from a different part in the code. I tried to call Stock.CallOnClick() but nothing happened.

If I understand `invoked from a different part in the code` correctly, you need to use `EditText.SetOnEditorActionListener(TextView.IOnEditorActionListener)`:

1. Create a new class inherits `java.lang.object` and `TextView.IOnEditorActionListener` and implement it:

   ```
   public class MyAction : Java.Lang.Object, TextView.IOnEditorActionListener
   {

       public void Dispose()
       {
           this.Dispose();
       }

       public bool OnEditorAction(TextView v, [GeneratedEnum] ImeAction actionId, KeyEvent e)
       {
           //insert your codes here
           return true;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Then you can pass an instance of `MyAction` to `SetOnEditorActionListener`:

   ```
   etStock = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etStock);
   etStock.SetOnEditorActionListener(new MyAction());
   ```